# Manipulate optional parameters in the WHERE clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlcommand

I'm working on a web-form that receives a string that contains an SQL query statement with SQL parameters. It generates an ASP.NET control for each parameter and then assigns the value of each control to the parameters of the SQL query string that will be used by a `SqlCommand` to fill a `DataAdapter`.

**I have some problems to manage the optional parameters.**

Ex.

*1) Pass the string to the page:*

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1=@P1 AND field2=@P2";
```

*2) Generate a web control for each parameter*

```
TextBox P1 = new TextBox();
P1.ID = "P1";
...
TextBox P2 = new TextBox();
P2.ID = "P2";
...
PanelParameters.Controls.Add(P1);
PanelParameters.Controls.Add(P1);
```

*3) On click pass the value of each parameters to the `SqlCommand` as parameters:*

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", P1.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", P2.Text);
```

*4) Right here it's OK!*

But if a parameter is **OPTIONAL** how can I manage it?

If P2 was optional, the user could not compile it and in that case I don't want to set `P2 = NULL` (setting the value of the parameter `DbNull.Value`), but I'd like that P2 will disappear from the query SQL.

Can you help me?

*** UPDATE ***
I can't edit the query that i receive because it contains very complex SQL statements.

Answer (score 5):

Change your query to the minimum :

```
string query="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1=@P1
```

Then append the rest with a condition :

```
if(P2.Text != "")
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2",P2.Text);
    query += " AND field2=@P2";
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's a very good idea but i can't change the query and then append because the query is received via an XML file that i read and often it is very difficult to decompose because of the complexity of the SQL statement.

Comment: You should update your question to show this. The only solution I see then is a component that analyse the received query and reconstruct it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using case statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1=@P1 AND CASE WHEN field2= null OR field2= '' THEN field2 ELSE @P2 END
```

You would still send the parameter, but if it's null or empty, it will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, very great method but I can't modify the query that i receive because the statement is often very complex and i can't find with precision every places where to insert the CASE STATEMENT parts...

Comment: Can you run the query after receiving it? Hold current values in memory and then if value is not null in textbox, replace with the new one. If textbox is empty, put the value you pulled previously.